# several images on one app

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

i try to create news app on django 1.8. And I suppose several images in one news that i can to add from the backend. So this is my models.py
from django.db import models

```
class Category(models.Model):

        category = models.CharField('Category', max_length=255)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.category

class Images(models.Model):

        image = models.ImageField('Images', upload_to='media/img/news')
        news = models.ForeignKey('News', blank=True, null=True)

class News(models.Model):

        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', blank=True, null=True)
        teazer_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img/news', blank=True)
        pub_date = models.DateField(null=True)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        short_content = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
        content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
        image = models.ForeignKey('Images', blank=True, null=True)
        meta = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from news.models import News, Category, Images
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Images

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [
                ImagesInline,
        ]

admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Images)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

But I do not understand how to create views and template. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Write your widget for multiple image upload. Iterate over the images that you get from post and save it in Images model and have a manytomany relation with news and associate it

Comment: I don't understand how to realize multiple image upload. Is it realized by formset_factory?

Comment: Like I said you can write widget that accepts multiple images